# Changing Touch ID dialog reason

Tags: ios, swift

I used below code to verify user by Touch ID

```
authenticationContext.evaluatePolicy(
.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,
localizedReason: "Only awesome people are allowed",
reply: { [unowned self] (success, error) -> Void in

if( success ) {

    // Fingerprint recognized
    // Go to view controller
    self.navigateToAuthenticatedViewController()

}else {

    // Check if there is an error
    if let error = error {

        let message = self.errorMessageForLAErrorCode(error.code)
        self.showAlertViewAfterEvaluatingPolicyWithMessage(message)

    }

}   })
```

It will show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBJ1Q.jpg)

While showing dialog for user verify by Touch ID, does it have any way for update localizedReson in realtime to show latest information without reshow dialog.

Comment: it have any way for update localizedReson in realtime to show latest information without reshow dialog. - which type of OP you expect

Comment: I mean I want to change "Only awesome people are allowed" text while dialog showing

Comment: ya you can change

Comment: how @Anbu.karthik